# Zend Framework: Initialize session (Database) error

Tags: php, zend-framework

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Exception' with message
>   'No adapter found for Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable' in
>   C:\wamp\www\hol\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php on line 755 ( ! )
>   Zend_Db_Table_Exception: No adapter found for
>   Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable in
>   C:\wamp\www\hol\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php on line 755 Call
>   Stack
>
> ## Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0005  373664  {main}( )   ..\init.php:0
>
> 2 0.0325  2749720 Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable->__construct(
>   ) ..\init.php:40 3    0.0325  2750168 Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->__construct(
>   ) ..\DbTable.php:207
>   4 0.0325  2750480 Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable->_setup(
>   ) ..\Abstract.php:268 5   0.0325  2750480 Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setup(
>   ) ..\DbTable.php:403
>   6 0.0325  2750480 Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupDatabaseAdapter(
>   ) ..\Abstract.php:739

Code:

```
//Configuration consumption
$config = new Zend_Config(require 'config.php');

//Database configuration
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->database->adapter, array(
    'host'     => $config->database->params->host,
    'username' => $config->database->params->username,
    'password' => $config->database->params->password,
    'dbname'   => $config->database->params->dbname
));

$sess_config = array(
    'name'              => 'session',
    'primary'           => array(
        'session_id',
        'save_path',
        'name',
    ),
    'primaryAssignment' => array(
        'sessionId',
        'sessionSavePath',
        'sessionName',
    ),
    'modifiedColumn'    => 'modified',
    'dataColumn'        => 'session_data',
    'lifetimeColumn'    => 'lifetime',
);

Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($sess_config));

//Initialize the session
Zend_Session::start();
```

config

```
<?php
// config.php
return array(
    'database' => array(
        'adapter' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
        'params'  => array(
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'dbname'   => 'hol'
        )
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'name'              => 'session',
        'primary'           => array(
            'session_id',
            'save_path',
            'name',
        ),
        'primaryAssignment' => array(
            'sessionId',
            'sessionSavePath',
            'sessionName',
        ),
        'modifiedColumn'    => 'modified',
        'dataColumn'        => 'session_data',
        'lifetimeColumn'    => 'lifetime'
    )
);
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `session` (
    `session_id` char(32) NOT NULL,
    `save_path` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `modified` int,
    `lifetime` int,
    `session_data` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Session_ID`, `save_path`, `name`)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to call `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db)` providing the `$db` object you created in your configuration example, as it appears you don't have a default DB adapter set up given the error, or you need to add the `$db` object to the `$sess_config` array so it gets set up as the DB adapter for `Zend_Session`.

`Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable` extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` and any options unknown to `Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable` (e.g. database configuration options) are then passed to the constructor of `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` which sets up the DbTable.

Try this:

```
$sess_config = array(
    'db'                => $db, // Pass the $db adapter as the 'db' parameter to Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
    'name'              => 'session',
    'primary'           => array(
        'session_id',
        'save_path',
        'name',
    ),
    'primaryAssignment' => array(
        'sessionId',
        'sessionSavePath',
        'sessionName',
    ),
    'modifiedColumn'    => 'modified',
    'dataColumn'        => 'session_data',
    'lifetimeColumn'    => 'lifetime',
);
```

Comment: By some reason my Apache server is crashing when I visit the page... but I can load any other file, like the config.php without problem.

Comment: @John Crashing as in a segfault or 500 internal server error?

Comment: It says the "program" have crashed, and then I am redirected to: http://localhost.se/hol/init.php instead of the usual adress http://localhost/hol/init.php

Comment: Does this happen on all pages that use a database connection?

Comment: No, just on the particular file init.php, all other files seems fine, when I remove "Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($sess_config));" it works again..  (I have no other file to test, since i just have one database file)

Comment: I think the crashing has to do more with a problem with PHP and MySQL modules.  I take it you are on Windows?  Nevermind, I see you are.  Probably there is a bug/inconsistency with the PHP version you have and the MySQL extenion that is being loaded into PHP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10200/discussion-between-drew010-and-john)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post the contents of your `config.php`, but based on the error I suspect you did not specify an adapter (mysql, pdo, etc).

My config file looks something like (yaml):

```
database:
  adapter: Pdo_Mysql
  params:
    host:     myhost
    dbname:   mydb
    username: myusername
    password: mypassword
```

According to the [Zend API docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html), you have to specify the adapter like this:

```
// Set this before you make the call to setSaveHandler()
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);

Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($sess_config));
```

Comment: I added the config file, I do have an adapter I am quite sure

Comment: Looks like you may have to add a database section to your $session_config array. The error `'No adapter found for Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable'`, refers to the array you passed to the `Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable` class.

Comment: I just did, look my comment in the answer below.

Comment: Ya you need to be a little more clear about "crashing". What specifically is happening?

Comment: "Apache have occured a problem and must close... " window pop up :S just on that particular file when I browse it.

Comment: Nothing. However if I remove "Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($sess_config));" it works again

Comment: Can you post your session schema?

Comment: The code you posted looks correct. Do you have the PDO module installed for PHP?

Comment: It was some problem with my server, I had, when I changed to Zend Server, it worked, thanks a lot for your effort